# Not able to delete contacts after writing trigger on contact

Tags: apex

## My trigger

```
trigger testtrigger on Contact (after insert,after delete,after undelete){

    id accountId;
    id accountsid;
    for(Contact c:trigger.new){
        accountId=c.AccountId;
    }
    Integer count=[select count() from contact where AccountId=:accountId];

     if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert){
         for(Account a:[select number_of_contacts__c from Account where id=:accountId]){
            count=count+1;
             a.number_of_contacts__c=count;
             update a;
         }
     }

if(trigger.isDelete){

    for(Contact c:trigger.old){
        accountsId=c.AccountId;
    }
         for(Account a:[select number_of_contacts__c from Account where id=:accountsId]){
            count=count-1;
             a.number_of_contacts__c=count;
             update a;
         }
     }

    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUndelete){
         for(Account a:[select number_of_contacts__c from Account where id=:accountId]){
            count=count+1;
             a.number_of_contacts__c=count;
             update a;
         }
     }

}
```

## Error

> Validation Errors While Saving Record(s) There were custom validation
>   error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first
>   validation error encountered was "Apex trigger testtrigger caused an
>   unexpected exception, contact your administrator: testtrigger:
>   execution of AfterDelete caused by: System.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.testtrigger: line 5,
>   column 1".

**i am not able to delete contacts**

Comment: This trigger is not written correctly and will fail if Contacts are involved from more than one Account. You need to bulkify the entire trigger.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to iterate trigger.new in delete case. Which you will get null and hence the exception.

SO you need to add trigger event check there

```
if(! trigger.isDelete) {
for(Contact c:trigger.new){
        accountId=c.AccountId;
    }
    Integer count=[select count() from contact where AccountId=:accountId];

     if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert){
         for(Account a:[select number_of_contacts__c from Account where id=:accountId]){
            count=count+1;
             a.number_of_contacts__c=count;
             update a;
         }
     }
}
```

[Trigger Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm)